# Function doesn't work as it should in IE7 & IE8 when invoked from a setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this crazy javascript issue with IE7 and IE8. The function expression below loads some images. That's it. quite simple. When the function is invoked directly ie `testmypatience()` it works as it should but if I call it from inside a timeout it won't load the images. The function is invoked but the images won't load. It also fails to work when invoked by the jQuery animate callback.

I've tried everything and i can't get it to work so you help would be most appreciated.

```
var testmypatience = function($active){
                var arr = ['images/site/products-medium/m_cordial_pomegranateelderflower.png', 'images/site/products-medium/m_cordial_spicedberry.png', 'images/site/products-medium/m_cordial_strawberryelderflower.png', 'images/site/products-medium/m_750presse_coxsapple.png', 'images/site/products-medium/m_party_appleandelderflower.png', 'images/site/products-medium/m_squeezy_blackcurrentandapple.png', 'images/site/products-medium/m_270presse_cranberryandorange.png', 'images/site/products-medium/m_270presse_elderflower.png', 'images/site/products-medium/m_270presse_gingerlemongrass.png'];
                for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    var img, len;
                    img = new Image();
                    img.src = arr[i];

                    img.onload = function(){
                        console.log('done ' + this.src);
                    }
                }
            }

//this works
testmypatience()

//None of these work
    setTimeout(function(){
       testmypatience()
    }, 400)

    setTimeout(testmypatience, 400)

    jQuery('elm').animate({left:'1000px'},
    {
       duration:200,
       complete: testmypatience
    });
```

Comment: I'd just like to add that when I say 'none of these work' above I mean  they do invoke the function but IE7 and IE8 don't fire the onload event and don't load the image.

Comment: You have to put 1000px within `""` perhaps. Works in Chrome if I do.

Comment: @pimvdb - that was just an example. I was just showing it being called from the Jquery method. the point it it doesn't work when invoked from the call back. I'll remove that bit from the code as it's clearly causing confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do it as complicated as you do in your solution. Just swap the assignment of `src`and `onload`.

**Wrong:**

```
img = new Image();
img.src = arr[i];
img.onload = function(){ ... }
```

**Right:**

```
img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){ ... }
img.src = arr[i];
```

Comment: Thanks man. That is the correct answer. Not entirely sure why users are +1'ing gonchuki's post as it's incorrect in relation to my question, even though I do appreciate his response as I would anyone who takes the time to reply to my questions. Stackoverflow is the nuts.

Comment: +1 - Just had to refer to your answer again. Thanks again for that;)

Answer (score 2):

IE7 and 8 don't have a console unless you installed a browser extension/plugin for that. Comment the lines with the `console.log` calls or use something like [FireBug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite)

Also as pimvdb says, the `1000px` should be in quotes (without quotes it breaks in all browsers, it's invalid javascript syntax).

Comment: IE9 has built a log console and it also allows you to select browser mode so you can see the output in ie7 and 8. It's not about the logging. the point i was making is the load method is never called when the function is invoked from a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

I've sorted it. I have to insert an empty image object into the dom first and then give it a src attribute and only then will it fire the onload event in IE7 and 8. Please feel free to ask any questions if I've been a bit vague and I will answer all your questions.

```
$(function(){
                var testmypatience = function($active){
                    var arr = ['images/site/products-medium/m_cordial_pomegranateelderflower.png', 'images/site/products-medium/m_cordial_spicedberry.png', 'images/site/products-medium/m_cordial_strawberryelderflower.png', 'images/site/products-medium/m_750presse_coxsapple.png', 'images/site/products-medium/m_party_appleandelderflower.png', 'images/site/products-medium/m_squeezy_blackcurrentandapple.png', 'images/site/products-medium/m_270presse_cranberryandorange.png', 'images/site/products-medium/m_270presse_elderflower.png', 'images/site/products-medium/m_270presse_gingerlemongrass.png'];
                    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                        var img, len;
                        img = new Image();
                        $(img).prependTo('body');

                        img.onload = function(){
                            console.log('done ' + this.src);
                        }
                    }

                    $('img').each(function(i, elm){
                        elm.src = arr[i];
                    })
                }

                setTimeout(function(){
                    testmypatience()
                }, 400)
            })
```